# Firebase returns duplicate values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get `posts` and `uid` from my Firebase Database. I'm using this:

```
mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("posts");
mPostReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String uid = (String) postSnapshot.child("uid").getValue();
                    String body = (String) postSnapshot.child("body").getValue();
                    Long num = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), body, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), num.toString(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            }
```

I'm getting the `num` value as `3`, but the data I get is duplicate. The same `body` & `uid` are fetched again and again. How do I stop at one iteration?

[image: My Database in firebase]

Comment: Which values are you getting repeatedly?

Comment: You say: _same body & uid are fetched again and again_.  I copied and ran your code on identically structured data.  I don't see the duplicates.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
Long num = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
```

Move this line of code outside for loop.